# Foreach MUCH faster than For in some cases?

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, foreach

I don't like premature optimization but I was curious while doing a simple task
so I added a stopwatch.
I don't understand how the difference can be so big.

Array of strings (7 characters) each [richtextbox.text].

Length of array: 5500 elements.

Foreach Elapsed Time: **0.0015 seconds**

For Elapsed Time: **9.757 seconds**

For:

```
if (chkLineBreaks.Checked)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < txtInput.Lines.Length; i++)
    {
        outputStringBuilder.Append($@"'{txtInput.Lines[i]}',");
    }
}
```

Foreach:

```
foreach (var line in txtInput.Lines)
{
    outputStringBuilder.Append($@"'{line}',");
    if (chkLineBreaks.Checked)
        outputStringBuilder.AppendLine();
}
```

From what I've read the difference should be negligible and the For would slightly faster.

Even more, the foreach has a condition in each iteration (unless it is being 'hoisted' up before the loop.

What is going on here?

Edit:
I've changed the foreach code to:

```
int i = 0;
foreach (var line in txtInput.Lines)
{
    outputStringBuilder.Append($@"'{txtInput.Lines[i]}',");
    i++;
}
```

So it is now doing the same thing.
It is taking **4.625 seconds**.. still about half of the time for the FOR

Also I know that I can extract the array outside the loop but this is not what I am testing here :)

Edit #2:
This is the whole code for that section:

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        //    for (int i = 0; i < txtInput.Lines.Length; i++)
        //    {
        //        outputStringBuilder.Append($@"'{txtInput.Lines[i]}',");
        //    }
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var line in txtInput.Lines)
        {
            outputStringBuilder.Append($@"'{txtInput.Lines[i]}',");
            i++;
        }
        MessageBox.Show(sw.Elapsed.ToString());
```

Comment: You might also want to try saving `txtInput.Lines.Length` to a variable, then using that variable in the conditional part of the for-loop. See how that affects performance.

Comment: 9 seconds come from somethings that isn't related to for/foreach. Probably some marshaling issue to/from a UI thread. Also note that the two tests are not equivalent, because in the foreach case, you also check chkLineBreaks.Checked.

Comment: There are too many differences in the code to come to any real conclusions.  If you really want a comparison make the two pieces of code exactly the same except for the 'for' and the 'foreach'.

Comment: Please check edit

Comment: internally the `foreach` command does a `for` loop when given an array of values. The results **should** be the identical if used properly.

Comment: Are you running this as a release build and outside of the debugger?

Comment: @JeroenMostert This is in release mode & running it through 'Start without Debugging' ie ctrl F5.
Visual Studio 2017, .NET 4.7 if anyone wants to reproduce.
Machine is 7700HQ & 16 gigs - not doing lots of background stuff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `txtInput.Lines` is executing many times (once per line) in your `for` loop (due to use of `txtInput.Lines[i]`). *So for every line of the file you are saying 'OK, please parse this textbox into multiple lines - and then get me the nth line' - and the parsing is the killer bit.*

For a fairer comparison:

```
if (chkLineBreaks.Checked)
{
    var lines = txtInput.Lines;
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        outputStringBuilder.Append($@"'{lines[i]}',");
    }
}
```

this way the `Lines` call is done only once (i.e. equivalent to the `foreach` scenario).

*One way to spot these kinds of issues is to compare the timings. The slow one is about 6K slower than the fast one, and you have 5.5K entries. Since 5.5K and 6K are very similar numbers, it may prompt you to think 'am I doing something in the loop that I really shouldn't?'*

Comment: I've changed the foreach to be identical to the for - Please check the edit.

Comment: @AngelicCore: that's still not the same thing. The `foreach` calls `txtInput.Lines.GetEnumerator()`, which only evaluates `.Lines` once. The `for` has to evaluate `.Lines` over and over again, unless you change the loop to what mjwills suggested.

Comment: Did what you asked - It is now back to 0.001 seconds for the FOR

Answer (score 1):

The compiled code sees very little difference between a `for` and a `foreach` statement when traversing an array (or list).

Consider this simple code the writes out a list of strings three different ways:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = Enum.GetNames(typeof(System.UriComponents));

        // 1. for each
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        // 2. for loop
        for (int i = 0; i<list.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(list[i]);
        }
        // 3. LINQ
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, list));
    }
}
```

Now look at the `MSIL` compiled code, translated back into `C#` using `ILSpy` or `DotNetPeek`.

```
// ConsoleApplication1.Program
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] list = Enum.GetNames(typeof(UriComponents));
    string[] array = list;
    for (int j = 0; j < array.Length; j++)
    {
        string item = array[j];
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(list[i]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, list));
}
```

See the two for loops. The `foreach` statement became a `for` loop by the compiler. As far as the `string.Join()` statement it calls the `SZArrayEnumerator` which holds a reference to the array, and the current index value. At each `.MoveNext()` call the index is incremented and a new value returned. Basically, it is equivalent to the following:

```
int i = 0;
while (i<list.Length)
{
    Console.WriteLine(list[i]);
    i++;
}
```